# how can I proxy wso2 identity server oauth2 api at wso2esb?

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Is it possible to create a pass thru proxy for identity oauth2 token service (https://:9443/oauth2/token) in wso2 esb/ei?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a passthrough  proxy in EI/ESB like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="token" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <endpoint>
            <address uri="https://:9443/oauth2/token" />
         </endpoint>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send />
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence />
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: hi Jenananthan

it required body form grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin to trigger the https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token, there is error when I trigger the pass thru proxy as per mentioned.
error log as below:
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-08-10 12:30:48,900] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils} -  Error while building Passthrough stream {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils}
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]

Comment: working after enable this 2 entries in axis2.xml

<messageFormatter contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
              class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
<messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
              class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>